# Usage of :not() to filter out elements in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm pretty confused by the [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). In plain CSS is seems to be rather straightforward:

```css
section { /* Overriden as expected */
  color: red;
}
input {
  color: green; /* In effect as expected */
}
:not(input) {
  color: blue; /* In effect as expected */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <input value="Lorem ipsum">
</section>
```

However, when applied to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger an event I'm unable to grasp the logic:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on("keydown", "input", function(event){
    // This fires only for <input> as expected
    console.log("Event handler #1 on", event.target);
  });  

  $(document).on("keydown", ":not(input)", function(event){
    // This fires for *all* elements :-?
    console.log("Event handler #2 on", event.target);
    // ... even though these checks return the results that intuition suggests
    console.log('Is "input"? %s; Is ":not(input)"? %s',
      $(event.target).is("input"),
      $(event.target).is(":not(input)")
    );
  });

  $(document).on("keydown", "section :not(input)", function(event){
    // This *never* fires :-?
    console.log("Event handler #3 on", event.target);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Click and type here</p>
  <input value="Click and type here">
</section>
```

What's the rationale behind the way `:not()` works here?

<sub>I'm really looking for an explanation as opposed to a fix.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the `keydown` event *bubbles* up from the `input`. If you use `:not(input)`, the handler will not fire when the event was just initialized at the `input` element, but it *will* fire when the event bubbles up to the `section` element. You can check this by checking `this` inside the function, which will refer to the element to which the event has bubbled when the handler fires. (The `event.target` will *always* be the `input` when you're typing in the input field)

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on("keydown", ":not(input)", function(event){
    // This fires for *all* elements :-?
    console.log("Event handler #2 on", this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Click and type here</p>
  <input value="Click and type here">
</section>
```

If you continue adding `:not`s, you'll see it bubble up all the way up to the HTML tag:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on("keydown", ":not(input):not(section):not(body)", function(event){
    // This fires for *all* elements :-?
    console.log("Event handler #2 on", this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Click and type here</p>
  <input value="Click and type here">
</section>
```

I suppose you *could* use `:not(input):not(section):not(body):not(html)`, but that's a bit silly and hard to manage.

Your third handler is properly excluding the `input` from firing the event, but *only* `input` (and similar) elements fire `keydown` events - it can't be fired from a `<section>`, for example. It might be clearer if there's a textarea child of the `section` as well as the input - you'll see that the textarea triggers the handler, but the input doesn't:

```js
$(document).on("keydown", "section :not(input)", function(event) {
  console.log("Event handler #3 on", event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <p>Click and type here</p>
  <input value="Click and type here">
  <textarea></textarea>
</section>
```

Comment: In other words: with white list selectors, event chain starts in your element; with black list selectors, it skips your element and starts one step upwards.